# -Xmx2048m is ignored by eclipse.ini

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

my eclipse based product eclipse.ini has below entry to accommodate 2GB of heap memory :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
-application xx.yy.zz.mm.application.application
-showSplash splash.bmp
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
```

When launched from exe is not working as the ini entry for Xmx is being ignored.

workaround : I am using now a batch file with below entry:

```
java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -Xss4m -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar -application xx.yy.zz.mm.application.application -showSplash splash.bmp
```

which is working fine but the solution looks ugly as users has to launch the application not from exe but from a batch file.
Any info would be greatly helpful.
I am using windows7 + 64bit JRE + eclipse Neon

Strange part is while the Xmx agrument is working fine from a batch file but why is not working from .exe+ini!
I don't know if we can debug the launcher or why the ini file is ignoring the 2048m memory.

Comment: Are you talking about an Eclipse RCP? An RCP uses a ini file with the same name as your RCP executable in the same directory are the RCP executable.

Comment: Yes greg-449 you are right I am talking about the launcher exe for my RCP application

Comment: So are you changing the ini with the same name as the RCP in the directory containing the RCP launcher exe?

Comment: yes ini and exe has same name . e.g. xxx.exe and xxx.ini

Comment: To check if the ini file has been read: *Help > About {product_name} > Installation Details > Configuration*: "System properties" section

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this problem with Oxygen, JDK 1.8.0.9 on Windows 10  :

-Xmx3000m didn't work.

Somewhere I was advised to try -XX:MaxPermSize=3000m
This didn't work.

[here](https://medium.com/@YattaSolutions/share-your-tweaked-eclipse-ini-with-profiles-for-eclipse-754d5cc4370) states:
Options starting with -X are implementation-specific and may not be applicable to all VMs.
MaxPermSize is non-standard option not understood by some non-Oracle JVMs, 
use the Eclipse startup option instead:

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
3000m

This will make the Eclipse launcher pass the MaxPermSize option to any JVM that supports it.

Comment: I've tried but no luck! my .ini entry looks like below :-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 3000m
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss4m
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC

Comment: My full .ini is too long to post here

Answer (score 0):

The ini file is very fragile, sensitive to whitespace and silently ignored in case there is any error. For example before the "startup" you have missed the '-' (probably just a C&P error!?).

In any case, I recommend to start with a clean/new/copied .ini. And then just add ONE new entry. To ensure nothing else is broken.

Comment: Yes Ame you are right about '-' part.I have copied and created a new ini file after adding one by one but of no luck.Lets see if I can do something else..